# How to find the phase difference between a sine and cosine function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently doing an online math course with little documentation and I've been having trouble finding resources on the process for solving a question like this. Essentially the question is:

Find the value of `a` inbetween `-period / 2`, `a`, and `period / 2` where the functions `cos(4.7x+3.7)` and `sin(4.7x+4.7a)` align/ aren't out of phase.

I understand what the question is asking me to do but I just cant figure out the process for finding a value of `a` *as well* as incorporating the in between this this and that part without graphing the two functions . To be clear I don't care about the answer I just would like to know how one should go about solving this and other problems like this.

Comment: Here, the expressions $4.7x+3.7$ and $4.7x+4.7a$ should be interpreted in radians, right?

Comment: @MattiP. I believe so all thought it isnt specified

Comment: I would approach this like so: Start with the equation
$$
\cos(4.7x+3.7) \equiv \sin(4.7x + 47.a)
$$
(I write "$\equiv$" because this has to be true for all values of $x$). Then we remember that $\sin y = \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}- y \right)$, so we can use this for the right-hand expression:
$$
\cos(4.7x+3.7) \equiv \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-4.7x - 47.a)
$$
Now we have an equation of the form $\cos \alpha = \cos \beta$, which has the solution $\alpha = \pm \beta + n2\pi$. Therefore
$$
4.7x + 3.7 = \pm \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-4.7x - 47.a \right) + n2\pi
$$
Can you continue from here?